# Ambassador AuthService Setup

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, grpc, api-gateway, ambassador

I am trying to set AuthService for my Ambassador Api Gateway. But in logs of that Ambassador pod I am getting this error:

```
<RichStatus BAD error='AuthService cannot support multiple proto values; using grpc' hostname='ambassador-9dcgs878-4dfs111' version='1.7.4'>
2021-12-03 21:33:05 diagd 1.7.4 [P94TAEW] INFO: cluster_extauth_127_0_0_1_8500_ambassador: <RichStatus BAD error='cannot merge cluster cluster_extauth_my_auth_uswest2_env1_9014_otls_no_cert_upstream_ambassador: mismatched attributes tls_context, grpc' hostname='ambassador-9dcgs878-4dfs111' version='1.7.4'>
2021-12-03 21:33:05 diagd 1.7.4 [P94TAEW] INFO: ambassador-auth.ambassador-p.1: <RichStatus BAD error='auth canary cluster_extauth_my_auth_uswest2_env1_9014_otls_no_cert_upstream_ambassador can only change service!' hostname='ambassador-9dcgs878-4dfs111' version='1.7.4'>
2021-12-03 21:33:05 diagd 1.7.4 [P94TAEW] ERROR: could not reconfigure:
```

My AuthService :

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: AuthService
metadata:
 name: myauth
 namespace: ambassador
spec:
 add_auth_headers:
   x-added-auth: auth-added
 add_linkerd_headers: false
 allowed_authorization_headers:
 - x-qotm-session
 allowed_request_headers:
 - x-example-header
 auth_service: my-auth.uswest2-env1:9014
 failure_mode_allow: true
 include_body:
   allow_partial: true
   max_bytes: 4096
 path_prefix: auth/check
 proto: http
 status_on_error:
   code: 403
 timeout_ms: 5000
 tls: true
```

FYI:
I have two clustor, first clustor have two namespace ambassador, ambassador-p. And other clustor have one namespace which has my-auth service. I am trying to deploy authService kind in ambassador namespace of clustor 1 and it will connect to authservice which is in second clustor. In namespace **ambassador-p** the ambassador_id is **ambassador_p** but for **ambassador** namespace, there is no ambassador id. Thats why I didn't specify ambassador_id in yaml config. Hence it should take **default**.

I tried same thing in ambassador-p namespace and it worked but it is not working in ambassador namespace. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was multiple authservice. I removed all authservice and added only the one which is above and it worked.
https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/running/services/auth-service/#canarying-multiple-authservices